# How to get orientation of the device(ipad) in grails code

Tags: ios, grails

I want to get the orientation of the device (ipad or iphone). We can get the user agent by using `request.getHeader("useragent")` in groovy code.

I need to get the orientation of the device i.e landscape or portrait mode in Groovy code. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Are you sure that it must be processed on server-side? Why not use js/css instead?

Answer (score 3):

In general, the server does not know anything about the physical dimensions of the client's viewport. The `request` hash merely gives you access to the HTTP headers included in the request. You would need to use Javascript to detect the size of the browser's window and make the appropriate changes on the client-side. In jQuery, you might begin with something like:

```
if($(window).width() > $(window).height()) {
  // Viewport is landscape, do something
} else {
  // Viewport is portrait, do something else
}
```

Comment: I would make in jquery as this, but also if you want, you can send a new http header from the mobile to the server saying what is the orientation!